# Error al guardar ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo estas dos clases

```
public class Invoice {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String title;

@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person person;

public Invoice(String title, Person person) {
    this.title = title;
    this.person= person;
}

public class Person{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String name;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Desde mi servicio hago lo sgte y esto funciona:

```
public Invoice create(CreateNewsRequest request) throws Exception {
    Person person = personRepository.findById(request.getPerson())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception());
    Invoice invoice= new Invoice(request.getTitle(), person);

    return newsRepository.save(invoice);
}
```

Si existe la persona guarda sin problemas pero si no existe me da error:

```
"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!
```

Comment: Faltan detalles: ¿la excepción es lanzada desde findById o desde save?

Comment: gracias, era en el findby, alguna propuesta de mejora de código apra realizar esa acción?

Comment: No hacer la consulta si request.getPerson() devuelve null